# Read value of outer class from inner class

Tags: java, global-variables, inner-classes, outer-classes

```
Public class Main {

    public static String s;
    String a="hello";
    String b="World";
    s=a+b; 

    class Demo{
        String m;
        m=Main.this.s; 
        System.out.println(m);
    }

}
```

Output should be : Hello World

I just here  try to understand main thing. 
My Main class is a Android Activity class which extends ListActivity and Demo class extends AsyncTask. I need to read value Static String s from doInBackground method.

Comment: output will be `helloWorld`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access any type of variable's value from `InnerClass`, you can dirrectly call that variable.

For this case, You have no need to use `Main.this` to access the our class's static variable...just call it as below...

```
m = s;
```

When you want to access a `static` object of one class from another class which isn't inner class then you need to use **Class Name** as...

```
m = Main.s;
```

not as...

```
m = Main.this.s;
```

So, your class should look like as below...

```
Public class Main{

    public static String s;
    String a="hello";
    String b="World";

    s = a + b; 

    class Demo{

        String m;
        m = s; 
        System.out.println(m);

    }
}
```

**Update:**

The result giving you `null` because you are inserting `non-static` value to a `static` object. Here, `a` and `b` are `non-static` and `s` is `static`. So, to get correct value you have to declare all of them as `static` as below...

```
    public static String s;
    static String a="hello";
    static String b="World";
```

Comment: But my output is null :(

Answer (score 0):

An Inner class can always directly access all the variables without using any object or class name. Hence you can directly refer to your outer class's variable without metioning its name.

Instead of `m=Main.this.s;` You can directly access variable s as `m=s;`

Its basic rule of Object Oriented Programming that Inner class has always full access of all the methods and variables of outter class.

Comment: Also String s is static you do not need this to access it.

Comment: But my output is null :(

Comment: @BDAndroidLover if you can post your actual code then it will be better to understand us.

Answer (score 0):

**-** First i won't show you the exact example what u mentioned here, because your problem is not this example **but to understand how to access inner class members**.

**Modified Example:**

```
package com.cyberfreaky.test;

public class Main {

    public static String static_string = "hello";
    public String nonstatic_string = "world";

    class Demo {

        String m = "";
        String n = "";

        public void getStaticString() {

            m = static_string;
            System.out.println(m);
        }

        public void getNonStaticString() {

            n = nonstatic_string;
            System.out.println(n);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main outerClass = new Main();
        Main.Demo innerClass = outerClass.new Demo();

        innerClass.getStaticString();
        innerClass.getNonStaticString();

    }

}
```

**In case of Android you can access the Outer Class member from Inner Class as below:**

```
package com.example.simpleservice;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int i = 0;
    static int x = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    class InnerClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            int a = i;
            int b = x;

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In the second example, int x is static and i not.
But
 int a = i;
 int b = x;
Assignment process is same ?